# Duda sobre como funcionaUpdateOrCreate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quisiera saber cómo funciona el método `UpdateOrCreate`, sé que la documentación explican esto:

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = App\Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

Pero no entiendo el funcionamiento para implementarlo en mi función, si alguien pudiera explicarme, estaría muy agradecido.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? o mejor ¿Qué SÍ entiendes del método?

Comment: Pues entiendo que puedo actualizar y crear a la vez, pero no entiendo como debería ser, según el id de mi tabla o alguna condición en especifica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método updateOrCreate() acepta dos parámetros de entrada, siendo obligatorio solo el primero, a continuación el código del mismo en el framework:

```
/**
 * Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with values.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  array  $values
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static
 */
public function updateOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
{
    return tap($this->firstOrNew($attributes), function ($instance) use ($values) {
        $instance->fill($values)->save();
    });
}
```

Lo que este método hace es:

1. Tomar el array de atributos (parámetro 1) y buscar en la base de datos si existe un registro que coincida con esos atributos, si no existe, entonces lo crea. En ambos casos (si existe o no el modelo) el método firstOrNew() entrega el modelo creado o encontrado.
2. Por medio del helper tap ([ver documentación)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-tap) se pasa el resultado de firstOrNew() al closure que está en el segundo parámetro de tap(), el cual utiliza el método fill (usado normalmente para actualizar registros con un array) para actualizar el registro con los valores del parámetro 2 que recibe el método updateOrCreate() y finalmente se guarda el modelo.

---

En otras palabras, en updateOrCreate() se pasa un array de atributos del modelo que se desean comparar, los que sean, no necesariamente el id o cualquier otro.